# Unknow Provider with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I am trying to request jason file with angularjs.I am using yeoman. These are my 3 files.

in view folder:main.html

```
<div class="jumbotron">


Choose A Category1
 <div class="wrap" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<select ng-model="selectedValue" ng-change="loadData()" >
  <option value="1">Category 1</option>
  <option value="2">Category 2</option>
  <option value="3">Category 3</option>
  <option value="4">Category 4</option>
  <option value="5">Category 5</option>
</select>



<div ng-show="selectedValue != null" class="main">
  <center><h2>Results For Category  {{ selectedValue }}</h2></center> <br><br>

</div>


<div  class="main"  >
  <ul class="cloudlist">
    <li class="service" ng-repeat="item in services" ng-click="select(item)">
      <div class="info">

        <h3>{{item.service_name}}</h3>
        <b>{{item.status_page}}</b><br>
        <b>Is Billed : {{item.is_billed.billing_term._identifier}}</b>


      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <br>
</div>

</div>
```

in controllers folder: main.js

```
'use strict';


angular.module('frontendApp')
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','Services', function ($scope, $http, Services) {
    $scope.loadData = function () {
        $scope.services = Services.query();
    };






$scope.select = function (item) {
       // do something with the item here when the service is clicked  
  };


}]);
```

in services folder: services.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('frontendApp').factory('Services', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/services/:serviceId', {
    serviceId: '@_id'
  }, {});
});
```

I get an error

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ServicesProvider <- Services
>   <- MainCtrl
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/unpr?p0=ServicesProvider%20%3C-%20Services%20%3C-%20MainCtrl
>   minErr/<@http://localhost:9000

Solution:
As I am using yeoman , I forgot to execute the command `yo angular:service Services`

Comment: Are you loading the main.js before loading the services.js ?

Comment: this is the hole code, I am not loading anything

Comment: You've got to reference the scripts somehow, either by `<script src="..">` to each one separately, or by a service that combines them all to one file for instance. How do you reference them ?

Comment: I am using yeoman, I thought he care about all this

Comment: @user567 how can any framework would know that I need to load js files automatically..without intimating to framework..

Comment: Not exactly sure how it's done with yeoman, but there needs to be something that tells it where to load files from. Easiest thing to start with is to check using dev tools if the services.js file is even loaded.

Comment: which yeoman generator are you using? There must be a gulp/grunt task that must be injecting files into your index.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code in your main.js

```
var module = angular.module('frontendApp', ['ngResource']);

module.factory('MyServices', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/services/:serviceId', {
        serviceId: '@_id'
    }, {});
}]);

module.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','MyServices', function ($scope, $http, MyServices) {
    $scope.loadData = function () {
        $scope.services = MyServices.query();
    };
}]);
```